# Show that there exists $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}^*_{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct, odd primes. Show that there exists $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}^*_{n}$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not elements in $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{n})^2$, and $\alpha\beta$ is not an element in $(\mathbb{Z}^*_{n})^2$.

Any help would be appreciated.